# Label only selected vertices with tkz-berge

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tkz-berge

I drew the following graph with `tkz-berge`, but only want vertices "v" and "u" to show up, how can I do this?

I've tried with `\AssignVertexLabel` but I seem to lack understanding of how to use it.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
%       \SetVertexNoLabel
        \SetUpVertex[FillColor=black, MinSize=8pt]
        \SetGraphUnit{2}
            \begin{scope}[rotate=0]
                \Vertices{circle}{u,b,v,d,e,f}
            \end{scope}
%       \AssignVertexLabel{u}{u}
%       \AssignVertexLabel{v}{v}
        \SetUpEdge[lw=1.5pt, color=black]
            \Edges(u,b,v,d,e,f,u)
        \SetUpEdge[lw=1.5pt, color=gray!70]
            \Edges(v,f,d)
            \Edges(d,b,e)
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily disable the automatic labeling with `\SetVertexNoLabel` before drawing the vertices, then activate it again with `\SetVertexLabel` after, and then use `\Vertex[Node]{u}` etc.

The `Node` option is necessary to indicate that `u` and `v` are referring to the already defined references `u` and `v` created with `\Vertices`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
  \SetVertexNoLabel % <--- ADDED
  \SetUpVertex[FillColor=black, MinSize=8pt]
  \SetGraphUnit{2}
  \Vertices{circle}{u,b,v,d,e,f}
  \SetVertexLabel % <--- ADDED
  \Vertex[Node]{u} % <--- ADDDED
  \Vertex[Node,Lpos=120]{v} % <--- ADDED
  \SetUpEdge[lw=1.5pt, color=black]
    \Edges(u,b,v,d,e,f,u)
  \SetUpEdge[lw=1.5pt, color=gray!70]
    \Edges(v,f,d)
    \Edges(d,b,e)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I didn't know you could just write \Vertices{circle}{u,b,v,d,e,f} :D Thank you for your help! :)